# Jquery deleting element in ".each" function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

I try to scrape a webpage using Node.js. I just want to delete the div node inside the link and get the string "John Doe". What am i doing wrong here ?

```
<div class="myclass">
<a href="page.html">
    <div><img src="image.jpg" /></div>
    John doe
</a>
</div>


$('div.myclass a').each(function(i, e) {
    $(e).each(function(i, e) {
        console.log($(e).remove("div").html());
    }
}
```

This javascript chunk of code return the exact same html part (the div isn't deleted)

```
<div class="myclass">
<a href="page.html">
    <div><img src="image.jpg" /></div>
    John doe
</a>
</div>
```

**Thanks for your help !**

Comment: Your jQuery doesn't work because your HTML is invalid. You can't have a block level `div` inside an inline `a`. Check your code in a DOM inspector and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Kay it's not really a solution though, just identifying the problem.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, the HTML 5 specification actually allows you to wrap block elements inside `a` tags. More info: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('div.myclass a').each(function (i, e) {
    $(e).each(function (i, ex) {
        $(ex).find("div").remove();
        $(ex).html();
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YxCEh/)

Even simpler

```
$('div.myclass a').each(function (i, e) {
    $(e).find("div").remove();
    $(e).html();
});
```

[**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/YxCEh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In your code the problem is with the line `$(e).remove("div")`, where it is trying to remove a `div` element from the matched set `e`, but `e` is the current `anchor` element so `$(e).remove("div")` will not remove anything, instead you need to find the `div` child inside the current `a` element and remove it.

Even if the html is invalid, you will be able to remove the `div`

```
$('div.myclass a').each(function(i, e) {
    $(this).children('div').remove();
    var text = $.trim($(this).text());
    console.log(text)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5LKyR/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you `children` function  too

```
$('div.myclass a').each(function(i, e) {
    $(e).each(function(i, e) {
        console.log($(e).children('div:first').remove(););
    }
}
```